# Stored Procedure if else syntax error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, if-statement

I try to use stored procedured first time in my project. So I have syntax error if I try to use "if","else".

If NewProductId equals "0" or null, I do not want to update.
else I want to update my NewProductId

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProcedured
(
@CustomerId INT,
@CustomerName VARCHAR(80),
@NewProductId INT
)
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE CUSTOMERS
SET    
CustomerName =@CustomerName ,

if(@ProductId !=null && @ProductId !=0)
{
ProductId =@NewProductId 
}

WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId 
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are mixing two different languages (C# with SQL). Would suggest using a SQL `CASE` statement to do this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyProcedured
(@CustomerId INT,
 @CustomerName VARCHAR(80),
 @NewProductId INT)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE CUSTOMERS
    SET CustomerName = @CustomerName,
        ProductId = CASE WHEN @ProductId IS NOT NULL AND ProductId <> 0
                         THEN @NewProductId
                         ELSE ProductId
                    END
    WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId 
END
```

Answer (score 2):

T-SQL is not C#

```
if @NewProductId is not null and @NewProductId <> 0
BEGIN
   UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET CustomerName =@CustomerName,
                        ProductId =@NewProductId 
   WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId 
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   UPDATE CUSTOMERS SET CustomerName =@CustomerName
   WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId 
END
```

Also notice that you don't have any variable named `@ProductID`. I suppose that you want to test the value in `@NewProductID`

Answer (score 0):

The `!=` sign is incorrect it should be `<>`instead.

```
if(@ProductId <> null && @ProductId <> 0)
```

Or Alternately

```
if(@ProductId is not null && @ProductId <> 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if @ProductId is not null and @ProductId <> 0
begin
    set @ProductId = @NewProductId 
end
```